# Grab the next cell above with a number in it - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, I need a formula to grab the contents from the next cell above that actually has a number in it, ignoring the empty cells, The column would be filled with this formula so there would be formulas in the cells above but some would be showing nothing because they will be contained in an IF statement such as =IF(E13="","", 'the formula').

If this function was in cell F13 it would look to F12 for a number if there was none then it would look to F11 and continue until it found a number and when it does it would show that number in cell F12.

This was the closest I got it skipped the first number above F12 and produced the number from the cell with a number above F12.

`=IF(E13="","",(IF(F12<>"", F12, INDEX(FILTER(F$1:F11, F$1:F11<>""), COUNT(F$1:F11)))))`

**Answer 1:**
I was able to get it to work with this adjustment adding "+1" after the COUNT function and removing the redundant IF statement by expanding the filter range:

`=IF(E13="","",(INDEX(FILTER(F$1:F12, F$1:F12<>""), COUNT(F$1:F12)+1)))`

**Best Answer** so far was by @Blindspots provided a more complete and direct solution looking for only numbers and allowing a message when no numbers were found:

`=IF(E13="",,IFNA(INDEX($F$1:F12, XMATCH(1, ARRAYFORMULA(ISNUMBER($F$1:F12)*1), 0, -1)),"None Found"))`

Comment: Would you please edit the question to describe the relevant scenario and include sample data and an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: In addition, it always helps to see a problem *in context* with real data and the actual layout. You may get more involvement if you share a link to a spreadsheet containing some realistic sample data and your manually-entered expected results alongside it.

Comment: I see you got a solution. Great. However, in reading your description of the problem and seeing the solution you accepted (which *does* address what you asked exactly as you asked it), I can't help but believe that A.) there is a more efficient approach and B.) you are likely dragging multiple formulas into place where a single formula can return the same results for all rows. The only way to know is to see the actual data and layout in context of the spreadsheet. I'm not trying to talk you into something; I'm just presenting the reality that a more efficient solution is likely possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Your Formula

You were close, you just needed to use COUNTA instead of COUNT.  That formula would not however differentiate between values that were numbers and text strings.

```
=IF(E13="",,INDEX(FILTER(F$1:F12, F$1:F12<>""), COUNTA(F$1:F12)))
```

## INDEX & XMATCH

XMATCH, unlike MATCH, allows searching from last to first.

```
=INDEX(range, XMATCH(1, ARRAYFORMULA(ISNUMBER(range)*1), 0, -1))

# OR

=INDEX(range, XMATCH(TRUE, ARRAYFORMULA(ISNUMBER(range)), 0, -1))
```

Using your example,

```
=INDEX(F$1:F12, XMATCH(1, ARRAYFORMULA(ISNUMBER(F$1:F12)*1), 0, -1))
```

## Explanation

1. The **`range`** is converted to an array of **`TRUE/FALSE`** values using ISNUMBER inside an ARRAYFORMULA then coerced to **`1/0`** by multiplying by **`1`**.
2. XMATCH searches for an exact match, **`match_mode=0`**, of the **`search_key`** in reverse order, **`search_mode= -1`**, and returns its row number (or an error if none is found).
3. INDEX uses that row number to return the right value from the original **`range`**
4. If no matches were made, the formula will return a **`#N/A`** error.
   You can optionally wrap it in the IFNA function to handle them:

   ```
   IFNA(value, value_if_na)
   ```

## Function Support

[ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)  [IFNA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944?hl=en)  [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)  [ISNUMBER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093296?hl=en)  [XMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12406049?hl=en)

Comment: That did the trick and more thank you. My final formula based on your answer:  

=IF(E13="","",IFNA(INDEX($F$1:F12, XMATCH(1, ARRAYFORMULA(ISNUMBER($F$1:F12)*1), 0, -1)),"None Found"))

Comment: You don't need to return **`""`** in Sheets, the comma will suffice: **`=IF(E13="",,value_if_true)`** Also, if the value you are looking for in `E13` is a number, you can use  **`=IF(E13,value_if_true,)`** as `E13` will return true for any number, false for a blank, and an error for a text string. Your original formula was close but it wouldn't tell the difference between a number and a text string.  I'll edit my answer to show the correction.